# Why is $a^k$ → $k$ mod $n$ one-to-one?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

My book states that any finite cyclic group $=\langle a\rangle$ of order $n$ is isomorphic
to $\mathbb{Z_n}$ under the mapping $a^k$ → $k$ mod $n$. This correspondence is one-to-one. I was wondering exactly why $a^k$ → $k$ mod $n$ is one-to-one. For example, if I work in $\mathbb{Z_5}$, then

$1^5$ → $5$ mod $5$,

and $1^{10}$ → $10$ mod $5$.

So, $5$ mod $5$ =$10$ mod $5$

would mean that $5=10$ which is a contradiction. Hope someone can help.

Comment: $5$ is the same thing as $10$ though when working in $\Bbb Z_5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this way:  since $\langle a \rangle$ has order $n$, the elements of $\langle a \rangle$ are
$$
e, a, a^2, \ldots, a^{n-1}.
$$
Define the asserted isomorphism using only those exponents, so you map $a^k$ to $k$ where $k$ is assumed to be on the list $0, 1, 2, \ldots, n-1$.  This makes it really obvious that it's a bijection.  Now, to prove it's an iso, you have to prove that the exponents act mod $n$ when you operate $a^ka^j=a^{k+j}$, but they do because of the Division Algorithm.

Edit for example:  suppose $a$ has order 12.  Then two such elements, as I've advertised them, are $a^{8}$ and $a^{10}$.  What is $a^8a^{10}$?  Well, it's $a^{18}$, but this is not one of the magic powers I am allowing you to use. That's okay, because I can long divide $18$ by $12$ and get $18 = 12+6$ so
$$
a^8a^{10} = a^{18} = a^{12+6} = a^{12}a^6 = ea^6 = a^6.
$$
So, all along $a^{18}$ was one of the magic powers in disguise, namely $a^6$.  Notice that this is exactly $18 \equiv 6 \bmod 12$ which explains the isomorphism.

Comment: The first part where we show that the mapping of $a^k$ to $k$ is bijective makes sense now. But, I'm still kind of confused about the second part where by proving it's an isomorphism, we have to prove that the exponents act mod $n$ when you operate $a^{k}a^{j}=a^{k+j}$.

Comment: @Sharon Edited to help/clarify maybe.